# Как передать параметры из командной строки в *.properties в Spring

Tags: postgresql, spring, spring-boot, maven, config

⠀⠀⠀⠀Всем привет! У меня есть REST API, которое работает на Spring Boot, а в качестве БД — PostgreSQL (сборщик Maven). Возникла потребность передавать параметры подключения к БД независимо от проекта, то есть, к примеру, в команде запуска `java -jar myapp.jar param1 param2 и т.д.`. Как это параметры потом прописать в файл *.properties у Spring, чтобы подключение к БД успешно произвелось?
Допустим, чтобы выглядело как то так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто переопределить через командную строку. `--spring.datasource.password=password` - это для Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: я имел ввиду как поставить свои значения на место ${db.host}, ${db.port} и т.д.

Comment: А смысл? Вы хотите их сохранить в этом файле после запуска?

Comment: смысл только в сокращении

Comment: Я все равно не вижу смысла, но вы можете просто доабвить также свои значения через `--db.username=username`